# uint8_t not printing the right value when casted to unsigned int

Tags: c++

I defined an `uint8_t` variable x and gave it the value `11110000`, but when I print it (casting it to an unsigned integer so it's not invisible), it prints out `112` when it should be `240`.
What did I do wrong ?

Also, I only need 4 bits, but I don't know any types which could provides me only 4 bits, which is why I use an `uint8_t`.

Brief code :

```
std::uint8_t walls;
walls=11110000;
cout << (unsigned int) walls <<endl;
```

Comment: 11110000 is not interpreted as binary. You are overflowing your `uint8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What did I do wrong ?

You didn't assign a base 2 value but a base 10 as you thought here:

```
walls=11110000;
```

To assign base 2 values use (at least with c++14 standard)

```
walls=0b11110000;
```

For older standards you can use

```
walls=0xF0;
```

> Also, I only need 4 bits, but I don't know any types which could provides me only 4 bits, which is why I use an uint8_t.

In fact `uint8_t` is the smallest number of bits you can have.

But you probably want to mask and only use the lower nibble:

```
walls=0b000011111;
```

or again for pre c++14:

```
walls=0x0F;
```

Answer (score 2):

`11110000` is being interpreted as a decimal number.

Which its binary representation is:

```
1010 1001 1000 0110 0111 0000
```

Since your variable is unsigned and overflow causes wrap around, the lower 8 bit are being assigned

```
0111 0000
```

Which is 112.

To use [binary constants](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html), simply add `0b` as suggested in comments.

```
walls=0b11110000
```

And apparently this is part of C++14. Thanks to @Daniel Kamil Kozar.